# Joining tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've parsed a .xls file using roo and stored the data in a relational database. Now I want to show those lines again, as it was in the .xls before. That is, I have to join 3 tables. How do I do that in Rails using active record methods ?

Suppose I have 3 tables: `Category`, `Subcategory` and `Item`. I need to show information from those 3 tables. I've done something like that in my models: `category has_many subcategory` and a `subcategory has_many items` (with the corresponding `belongs_to` of course). How would I iterate in each `category` and get the `subcategory` and the `items` in an active record way ?

Comment: You can use [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

Answer (score 0):

```
categories= Category.all

sub_categories = categories.collect{|category| category.subcategories }.compact

items = sub_categories.collect{|sub_cat| sub_cat.items}.compact
```

something like this should work

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve categories, subcategories and items using active record:

```
@categories = Category.includes(:subcategories => :items)
```

This will eager load the associations, and avoid N+1 select issues.

Then you can iterate them as usual, using `each`:

```
@categories.each do |c|
  c.subcategories.each do |s|
    s.items.each do |i|
      # do something with item i
    end
  end
end
```